# Get hovered element d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'points')
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.date))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.close))
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", "#364652")
    .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
          console.log(this)
     })
```

In the example above - `this` returns window, so `d3.select(this)` inside of that function is not working, like it did in v3 version examples.

How can i get element, that been hovered with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that i'm using arrow function, so it binds context on creation.

If you want to get element that triggered event, you should use regular function expression:

```
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'points')
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.date))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.close))
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", "#364652")
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          console.log(this)
     })
```

Comment: an arrow function does **not** bind this

Comment: @rioV8 rly? any links?

Comment: maybe in the docs about JavaScript. search "JavaScript Arrow Function"

Comment: @rioV8, yep, I’ve read that already, and docs are saying that it gets binded where it’s declared.